# jquery ajax call to ASP.NET MVC controller returns a MediaTypeFormatter exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, breeze, durandal

Technical Background - We're using :

1) asp.net 4.5 with VS2012 
2) Durandal JS for building Single-Page-Apps (SPAs).
3) Breeze JS for querying data.

Now in my jquery ajax call, I'm calling into the Breeze Web API controller as follows:

```
    jsonData.push({
        "nodeType": vm.nodeType,
        "nodeDescription": vm.nodeDescription,
        "NodeDefs": ds.data()      // ds dataset is coming from a grid
    });        

    var jsonDataStr = JSON.stringify(jsonData);         CONVERT DATA TO JSON
    var jq = $.ajax({
        url: '/api/breeze/UpdateNode/',
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json",
        data:jsonDataStr,
        async: false,
    });
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public SaveResult UpdateNode(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        SaveResult saved = new SaveResult();
        return saved;
    }
```

However I'm getting the following exception return from my jQuery FAILED EVENT :

"ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JObject' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

So my main question is: how can I make a successful call into my Breeze API controller with the correct JSON data ?

UPDATE AT 1:50pm EST: If I specify type: "STRING" or "JSON" in my jquery ajax call, define my parameter type as STRING in my c# Controller method, the call works fine. However, ideally I want to pass this data object as JSON and my controller should handle it properly.

Thanks in advanced.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will need [BreezeController] attribute as mentioned here http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my javascript code to NOT use the javascript array and the subsequenst jsonData.push() and stringify().

Instead I needed a straight jsonData={} object as follows :

```
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
        "nodeType": vm.nodeType,
        "nodeDescription": vm.nodeDescription,
        "NodeDefs": ds._data     // gives me just the data from Kendo grid data source
    });
```

I was then able to successfully make an ajax call to my controller as follows :

```
        var jq = $.ajax({
        url: '/api/breeze/UpdateNode',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: jsonData 
    });
```

All is good and I'm able to nicely put a break point inside my controller and receive the JObject parameter with issue.

thank you.
Bob